# Convert string stored in mysql into php again: eval()

Tags: php, mysql, json, eval

I have a problem. In my MySQL database, I have a column storing the output of a PHP object (as a string):

```
Array
(
    [item_id] => 849
    [title] =>
         Array
         (
             [0] => hello
             [1] => bye bye
         )
    ......
```

If I run eval on that, it ofcourse will not work. Is there a function or known technique to getting this back into a php object, or will i have to store in mysql as json (that will be a massive pain).

Comment: How is that going into the database? Or: why not use `serialize` and `deserialize` ?

Comment: I control this process, but i've already gone ahead and stored like thousands of rows of data and it's gnna be a real heave to get that stored as seralize or json again. :( choice?

Comment: You stored the output of print_r() and expect to be able to parse it again?

Comment: Why do you use a database then? Anyway you should be able to migrate to another schema, no matter how many "thousands" rows of data you have - that's the purpose of programming!

Comment: Tip: don't do it again. Don't put serialized data in a database; create a proper schema.

Comment: God damn your answers. I was hoping someone had already done this mistake and written a nice little regex but okay. I'll go back and re-process the s to the t out of this. *shivers* Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JamesT the duplicate link I gave you has a link in the answer that does it for you.

Comment: The data comes from an API as PHP objects, I don't know what a schema is?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema ;). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Bart, i'll store this code as json, butr yours is the answer i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to go you need either use serialize/unserialize or json strings:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: Better is not to serialize and put proper data in a database. That is what they are for.

Comment: Bart, i am getting objects from an API... In this instance, I'm doing it correctly, I just made a mistake of not storing it as json first. The API layout changes often and so creating a database structure for this information would be a waste of time.